# Angularjs: Autofill textbox values from database by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This are my code on view:

```
input type="text" name="passno" ng-keyup="fetchdata()" class="form-control" ng-model="FormData.passno"

input name ="firstname" type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="FormData.fname" ng-disabled="isDisabled"

input  name="lastname"  type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="FormData.lname" ng-disabled="isDisabled"
```

On controller side:

```
$scope.FormData = {passno:''};
    $scope.fetchdata = function() {

        $scope.$watch('FormData.passno',function(){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'server/company/getPassnoData',
            data: {passno:$scope.FormData.passno },
            headers: {'X-API-KEY': $rootScope.currentUser.key}

        })
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.autofill = data;
                if(data) {
                    SweetAlert.swal({
                        title: "Warning?",
                        text: "User with this passport number is already registered as "+$scope.autofill.CandData.f_name,
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: "Auto Fill",
                        cancelButtonText: "Reset",
                        closeOnConfirm: false,
                        closeOnCancel: false
                    }, function (isConfirm) {
                     if (isConfirm) {                           

    $scope.FormData.fname= $scope.autofill.CandData.f_name;
$scope.FormData.lname= $scope.autofill.CandData.l_name;
});
```

My problem is sweet alert will generate alert properly. When I click on autofill it shows success, but textbox values cant display until I click manually on specific text box it will then display all values on textbox, but I want just display as by clicking on autofill. Basically **I want to display text box values dynamically**. I only take input for passport number field than it send request and result comes for firstname, lastname field which I have to display dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change anything inside non-angular components it won't run `$digest` to make effect of changes to everywhere it linked.

You need to apply changes for non-angular components.

Add **[`$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)**

Like this

```
$scope.FormData.fname= $scope.autofill.CandData.f_name;
$scope.FormData.lname= $scope.autofill.CandData.l_name;
$scope.$apply()
```

or like this

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.FormData.fname= $scope.autofill.CandData.f_name;
    $scope.FormData.lname= $scope.autofill.CandData.l_name;  
})
```